# how to set the width and height of the Image after export to PDF by ITextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, itext

Currently I using ITextSharp for exporting my gridview to pdf. My gridview have an Image file and it's width will expend to 125% and height also to 125% percent. 
My questions are:

- how do i set the image to widht:80px and height:100px.
- after set the image width and height, how to insert it to the gridview?

besides that, after i export the gridview to pdf file, the image will go out of the cell. What is that and how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this post in MikesDotnetting](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images). Another post about [working with tables in iTextsharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables) is also there

See a sample code for working with tables

```
// adding content to iTextSharp Document instance
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
                //actual width of table in points
                table.TotalWidth = 500f;
                //fix the absolute width of the table
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                //relative col widths in proportions 
                float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 2f, 1f };
                table.SetWidths(widths);
                table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                //leave a gap before and after the table
                table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                table.SpacingAfter = 10f;

  //Start Heading
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { BorderColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Phrase = new Phrase("No.", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD)) });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { BorderColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Phrase = new Phrase("Item Name", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD)) });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { BorderColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Phrase = new Phrase("Description", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD)) });

// Table content
//Here we can use a loop to add multiple rows
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { BorderColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Phrase = new Phrase("1", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL)) });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { BorderColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Phrase = new Phrase("Register Book"), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL)) });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { BorderColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, Phrase = new Phrase("Used to manage the details"), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL)) });
```

Here you can see a three column table. For adding multiple rows you can loop the table content part in the code.

Pass the values from code as shown.

Comment: but the "http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images" i had look at it before it is use document.add. i think it is not suitable.but thank you very much. i looking at "http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables" this 1st.

Comment: ok... "http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables" this is nice. but i export the from gridview. so, how i add the gridview cell to the table.addcell, since it is disallowed. and the gridview got 6 column and more than 10 rows...how can i do?

Comment: this is also is other things i want. but right now i have some issue. how i get the data from the gridview?and wat if i have nested gridview. how i get the data? sorry for troublesome.

Comment: Which datasource you are using to bind the gridview? For iTextSharp, you need to pass those values tomrender the PDF. For image rendering you need to give the accurate path. Also note that, the PDF is generated correctly if you provide the data to the AddCell method. The Mikes Article has a good explanation regarding it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I using objectDatasource for binding gridview. i already had export all the data include image to the pdf. but, the image change to 125% larger in the pdf while in the gridview is only 80px * 100px . i dun know wat is the problem so just try to export it to a pdfPTable. do i did wrong? or do u know wat is the problem i did for causing the image become 125% larger during exporting. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The image size for the PDF should in points(pt) while using iTextSharp. Convert the corresponding pixel value to points value.

Comment: I see...let me try 1st. Thanks a lot for u

Comment: ok...the image is work...but just left the other data cells...thanks for your help so long ...